# Best way to connect and save data in an online Android game

Tags: unity, c#, android, mysql, photon

I'm new here, I'm in need of a help as it would be the most ideal way to proceed with my project.

The project is very simple, a basic online rpg for android in specific (in the future can be migrated to other OS), done in unity3d and c #, at the moment I'm using the Photon Network to connect, but I do not know how to save the data Character, intended to connect to mysql and save the data.

Is this method good?

And which would be the most appropriate to save the data?

> Sorry Google Translated!

Comment: You should try [pt.so] if they handle this :)

Comment: "What's the best way to do X" rarely has a wholly objective answer. Nearly every choice we have in gamedev is between alternatives with trade-offs, pros & cons. Framed another way: the best way for you to do something is the way that works for you. So, you mention you intend to use mysql - does this solution work for you? If so, great - you're done! If it's *not* working for you, then try editing your question to describe the specific problem you're having making it work. We won't be able to give you a full tutorial - search the web for that - but we can help you with a specific step/issue.